# Multiple missiles/bullets in a space invader clone (First go at a game with python)

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I'm a beginner programmer and my first language is Python 2.7, I'm trying to make a space invader type game but i want to have multiple bullets at once and cant find a way to do that. so i made my own way here is my code ill explain more after you see it

```
        if event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key==K_SPACE:
            if m < 5:
                m+=1

            if m==1:
                m1a=1
                m1x=ls

            if m==2:
                m2a=1
                m2x=ls

            if m==3:
                m3a=1
                m3x=ls

            if m==4:
                m4a=1
                m4x=ls

            if m==5:
                m5a=1
                m5x=ls

            print m
#missle 1
    if m1a==1:
        screen.blit(rship,(m1x,m1))
        if m1>=0:
            m1-=1
        else:
            m-=1
            m1a=0
            m1=460
#missle 2
    if m2a==1:
        screen.blit(rship,(m2x,m2))
        if m2>=0:
            m2-=1
        else:
            m-=1
            m2a=0
            m2=460
#missle 3
    if m3a==1:
        screen.blit(rship,(m3x,m3))
        if m3>=0:
            m3-=1
        else:
            m-=1
            m3a=0
            m3=460
#missle 4
    if m4a==1:
        screen.blit(rship,(m4x,m4))
        if m4>=0:
            m4-=1
        else:
            m-=1
            m4a=0
            m4=460
#missle 5
    if m5a==1:
        screen.blit(rship,(m5x,m5))
        if m5>=0:
            m5-=1
        else:
            m-=1
            m5a=0
            m5=460
```

I'm sure its laughably noobish but I'm just learning but the problem is the first and second missile are fine its the third and beyond that get messed up. when you fire the third it moves the second over the where your shooting from and then if you fir again the code wont go back down to 1 it stays at 2 and gets even more glitches. If you need me to try and explain it better I gladly will. Just trying to Learn.

Full code here: pastebin.com/FnPaME6N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some working code, but I wouldn't call it great.

```
import pygame
import math
from pygame.locals import *
background_colour = (122, 100, 155)
(width, height) = (500, 500)

pygame.init()

#ship = pygame.image.load('lolol.jpeg')\
rship = pygame.image.load('js.jpg')
mis = pygame.image.load('lot.jpg')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A.N.T.O.N.I.A.')
screen.fill(background_colour)
pygame.display.flip()
running = True

MAX_MISSILES = 5

ls = 250  # Horizontal ship location

LEFT = False
RIGHT = False

def move(ls, RIGHT, LEFT):
    '''Moves the ship 3 pixels to the left or right.

    Only moves if just one direction key is down, and not both.
    Also, will not move if the ship is at either horizontal screen edge.

    ls is the ship location.

    '''
    if LEFT and not RIGHT:
        if ls >= 10:
            ls -= 3
    elif RIGHT and not LEFT:
        if ls <= 440:
            ls += 3
    return ls

def fire_missile(ls, missiles):
    '''Fire a missile, as long as we are not at the maximum number.

    We use a list to hold our missile locations.

    '''
    if len(missiles) >= MAX_MISSILES:
        return
    else:
        missiles.append((ls, 460))

def draw_missiles(missiles):
    '''Draw all the missiles.'''
    if missiles:
        for missile in missiles:
            screen.blit(mis, (missile))

def move_missiles(missiles):
    '''If there are any missiles, move them up 1 pixel, and append
    them to the newlist.  The new list will replace the old list.

    '''
    if missiles:
        newmissiles = []
        for missile in missiles:
            # Do not append the missile to the new list if it is going
            # off the screen
            if missile[1] > 0:
                newmissiles.append((missile[0], missile[1] - 1))
        return newmissiles
    else:
        return missiles

missiles = []

while running:
    screen.blit(rship, (ls, 450))
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.fill(background_colour)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            # You can now quit with the escape key.
            pygame.quit()
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_LEFT:
            LEFT = True
        # LEFT is True untli you let up in the LEFT key
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == K_LEFT:
            LEFT = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            RIGHT = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            RIGHT = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
            fire_missile(ls, missiles)
    ls = move(ls, RIGHT, LEFT)
    draw_missiles(missiles)
    missiles = move_missiles(missiles)
```

Any time you find yourself making variables with numbers in them, it's a code smell, and means you probably should use a different data type.

As has been suggested, you'll probably want to look into the sprite and group modules, but this will at least do what you were trying to do so far.

Comment: im sure i am doing it very wrong. thanks for the honesty ill post the full code to pastebin in just a sec thank you for the reply http://pastebin.com/FnPaME6N

Comment: I'll be back later, and I'll post you some feedback.

Comment: @jgritty: This is not an answer. Please post it as a comment instead.

Comment: Thank you. ill be studying this code to learn exactly how it works thank you for explaing what each set does it will help alot!

Comment: super noob question impending... but how did you make your def statements run without calling them? :/

Answer (score 1):

You should make your "bullets" [sprites](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) and then add them to a [group](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) called `bullets` or something. Calling the `update` method on the group will update all your bullets in a single go.

Comment: But then how will i make them all move up the screen? my main issue is that to make them go up the screen i change the values at which there blited to, however i cant think of a way to make it work correctly. But i will look more into the sprite function. i was going to do it with sprites but it seemed overly complicated for what i need to do. i think i underestimated the complexity of bullets o.O that's coding for you.

Comment: Each sprite will know where it is and should be aware of what direction it should go so their individual `update` methods will have a `y-=1` or something similar.

Comment: Each sprite has a rect. calling `update` auto-moves their rect.top -= 10. Later, you can instead have x and y velocities, so bullets can move into any direction.